# Comparing redis client-side caching to redis replication

Tags: redis, replication

I have a very large geospatial index in redis that I replicate to application servers and query using `SINTERSTORE` operations on read-write replicas.

I would like to understand if [redis server-assisted client-side caching](https://redis.io/topics/client-side-caching) could be used as an effective substitute for this architecture.

Specifically, if I use the `BCAST` option and specify no prefix, have I effectively achieved the same thing as redis replication? Based on the article above,

> If no prefix is specified at all, the prefix is assumed to be the
> empty string, so the client will receive invalidation messages for
> every key that gets modified.
>
> Every time a key matching any of the prefixes is modified, all the
> clients subscribed to such prefix, will receive the invalidation
> message.

I would note that replication has [extensive discussion](https://redis.io/topics/replication) about what happens where there are network disruptions; no such conversation exists WRT server-assisted client-side caching. I wonder if this is one of the differences?